# scipy + (numpy.distutils-based) setup.py + ctypes: undefined symbol

Tags: python, c++, numpy, scipy, shared-libraries

#### Intro

As a follow-up to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139483/scipy-ctypes-build-config-how-to-load-lib), i still try to:

- add new functionality to one of scipy's modules (e.g. `scipy.optimize`)
- based on C++-code

  - which defines an interface-function to be called with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)
- automatically setup through `setup.py` in `scipy/optimize`

#### Code incorporation

To keep it simple, let's assume we got the following (dumb and) simple C++-code:

```
extern "C" void hallo()
{
    int a = 0;
}
```

where we use the `extern` keyword to handle name-mangling.

We introduce new files and folders in `scipy.optimize`:

```
scipy/optimize/__init__py
scipy/optimize/lbfgsb/...
scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py
...
scipy/optimize/_mylib/README.md       # new
scipy/optimize/_mylib/LICENSE         # new
scipy/optimize/_mylib/src/debug.cpp   # new
scipy/optimize/mylib.py               # new
```

#### Setup preparation

We prepare the module-setup in `scipy/optimize/setup.py`:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

from os.path import join

from scipy._build_utils import numpy_nodepr_api

def configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None):
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info
    config = Configuration('optimize',parent_package, top_path)

    # MODIFICATION START
    # OTHER EXTENSIONS OMITTED 
    # INSPIRED BY scipy.spatial: ckdtree/src & setup.py

    mylib_src = ['debug.cpp']
    mylib_src = [join('_mylib', 'src', x) for x in mylib_src]

    mylib_headers = []
    mylib_headers = [join('_mylib', 'src', x) for x in mylib_headers]

    mylib_dep = mylib_headers + mylib_src

    config.add_extension('_mylib',
                         sources=mylib_src,
                         depends=mylib_dep,
                         include_dirs=[join('_mylib', 'src')])
    # MODIFICATION END    

    return config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
```

#### Run scipy install

Installing scipy now (from base-dir) with:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

works and we will see those shared-libraries in `scipy/optimize/`:

```
_lbfgsb.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
...
_mylib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

#### Let's try to use it / a look into scipy/optimize/mylib.py

As seen in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139483/scipy-ctypes-build-config-how-to-load-lib), we can get the lib with (we are in `scipy/optimize/mylib.py`) and get the function we want to use:

```
import scipy as scp
import numpy.ctypeslib as ctl
lib = ctl.load_library('_mylib', scp.optimize.__file__)
myfunc = lib.hallo
```

**Now here is the problem:** this fails with:

```
AttributeError: /.../_mylib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: hallo
```

Trying it per hand:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL('full path to above so')
myfun = lib.hallo
```

fails too.

**But**, checking (on my linux OS): `nm --defined-only _mylib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` outputs:

```
...
...
0000000000000530 t hallo
...
```

which should be ok. (Disclaimer: i absolutely miss any knowledge about C++ linking). **Edit:** maybe it's not okay. See later observation in regards to `t vs. T`!

#### Doing it manually: this works

Going to `scipy/optimize/_mylib/src`:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC debug.cpp -o mylib.so
```

followed by `nm --defined-only mylib.so` shows the same functions, but some `t` became `T`.

```
...
...
0000000000000600 T hallo
...
```

Probably this is the reason, and there is some related general question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531846/nm-symbol-output-t-vs-t-in-a-shared-so-library).

As mentioned, this works:

```
# in src
import numpy.ctypeslib as ctl
lib = ctl.load_library('mylib.so', '.')
lib.hallo
# < FuncPtr object at 0x....
```

But what needs to be done in `setup.py` or my sources to make it work?

During running scipy-install, output looks like:

```
building 'scipy.optimize._mylib' extension
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/scipy/optimize/_mylib
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/scipy/optimize/_mylib/src
compile options: '-Iscipy/optimize/_mylib/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy-1.15.0.dev0+e4d678a-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c'
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++: scipy/optimize/_mylib/src/debug.cpp
scipy/optimize/_mylib/src/debug.cpp: In function ‘void hallo()’:
scipy/optimize/_mylib/src/debug.cpp:3:9: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int a = 0;
         ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/scipy/optimize/_mylib/src/debug.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5 -o scipy/optimize/_mylib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -Wl,--version-script=build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/link-version-scipy.optimize._mylib.map
```